# Styling Images based on array of images from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm trying to write code to display images that are coming from a CMS in a JSON file.

The JSON file would be like this

```
{  
 "images": [
  {"title": "Image One", "url": "image1.jpg"},
  {"title": "Image Two", "url": "image2.jpg"},
  {"title": "Image Three", "url": "image3.jpg"},
  {"title": "Image Four", "url": "image4.jpg"},
  {"title": "Image Five", "url": "image5.jpg"}
 ]
}
```

The HTML would be this

```
<ul id="mylist"></ul>
```

The number of images that are being loaded are dynamic. It can be anything among 3, 4, or 5. Here's how the layout should look for each one.

- For three images, each image should take 33% of the width [image]
- For four images, each image should take 50% of the width, in two rows [image]
- For five images, three images in the top,each occupying 33%, remaining two occupying 33% and 33% in the second row. [image]

Does anybody know how to achieve this with JavaScript, jQuery, mustache, etc???

Comment: What should happen if the screen width goes down very small (for example, on an iPhone)? Should each image continue taking up only 33% of the page width?

Comment: @vamshi If there are 8 images then what should be ? 3 , 3, 2 OR 2,2,2,2

Comment: @jsve in that case, images will take 100% width.

Comment: @mmuzahid 8 images is not the case here. Are going to deal with only 4,5 or 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like just basic math, if you have an even number of images, you want two columns, if you have an odd number of images you want three columns.

Once you know the number of columns, getting the number of rows is just a  matter of dividing and rounding up

```
var numb = obj.images.length;

var cols = numb % 2 === 0 ? 2 : 3;
var rows = Math.ceil(numb / cols);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/43uqezy8/1/)

Changing that to widths is easy

```
var numb = obj.images.length;

var width = numb % 2 === 0 ? '50%' : '33%';

$('.images').css('width', width)
```